# How to generify Reactor function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have the following static function to log some info before another flux is called.

```
public static Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>> logBefore(Consumer<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>> consumer) {
     return Flux.<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>>empty()
            .doOnEach(logOnComplete(consumer));
}
```

I call the function as follows:

```
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {

   return logBefore(r -> log.info("[Enter] myMethod() called."))
       .switchIfEmpty(client.retrieveData(request));
}
```

How to generify this function? I have tried something as follows:

```
public static <T> Flux<T> logBefore(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return Flux.<T>empty()
            .doOnEach(logOnComplete(consumer));
}
```

However, the compiler is complaining.

```
Required type:Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>>
Provided:Flux<Object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference unfortunately does not go deeper than 1 level. That means that type inference tries to get the actual type of `T` when calling `logBefore(r -> log.info("[Enter] myMethod() called."))` from its argument. That's so generic that no proper type can be inferred, and therefore object is used.

Two ways to get around this:

1. Tell the method what the generic type should be:

```java
return ClassWhereLogBeforeIsDefined.<ServerSentEvent<MyObject>>logBefore(r -> log.info("[Enter] myMethod() called."))
```

2. Tell the lambda what the generic type should be:

```java
return logBefore((ServerSentEvent<MyObject> r) -> log.info("[Enter] myMethod() called."))
```